# Spawning hundreds of rigidbody2d enemies that follow player while keeping up performance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, optimization

So I'm creating a 2D top-down endless shooter game and need enemies to spawn faster as time goes on. The enemies health also scales with the player level. I'm using Unity 2020.1.4.

The problem I have is that at a certain point the framerate just drops cause of the amount of rigidbodies in the scene at the point in time.

Is there any way I can redo this or refine it to make it less resource intensive?

Code:

public class EnemySpawn : MonoBehaviour
{

```
public GameObject[] enemies, bossEnemy;

float bossTimer;
public float timeForBoss, bossTime, startTimeForBoss = 60f;

public float spawnRadius = 7f, time, defaultTime = 3f;

public float fasterSpawnIncrements, spawnIncTimer, spawnIncTimerHolder;

public bool timerDecreased = false;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    time = defaultTime;
    spawnIncTimerHolder = spawnIncTimer; //Set timers for making enemies spawn faster over time
    StartCoroutine(SpawnAnEnemy());
    bossTimer = startTimeForBoss; //Set timers for making bosses spawn faster over time
    timeForBoss = 60f;

}

void FixedUpdate()
{

    spawnIncTimerHolder -= Time.deltaTime; //Decrease timer for enemies

    while (spawnIncTimerHolder <= 0)
    {

        time *= fasterSpawnIncrements; //Decrease time between enemy spawns
        spawnIncTimerHolder = spawnIncTimer;

    }

    bossTimer -= Time.deltaTime;

    if (bossTimer <= 0)
    {
        StartCoroutine(SpawnABoss());

        if (timeForBoss > 8)
        {
            timeForBoss -= 4f;
            timerDecreased = true;
        }

        if (timeForBoss <= 8 && timeForBoss > 3)
        {
            timeForBoss -= 2f;
            timerDecreased = true;
        }

        bossTimer = timeForBoss;
    }

}


IEnumerator SpawnAnEnemy()
{

    Vector2 spawnPos = GameObject.Find("Player").transform.position;
    spawnPos += Random.insideUnitCircle.normalized * spawnRadius; //Set allowable spawn point area around the player

    Instantiate(enemies[Random.Range(0, enemies.Length)], spawnPos, Quaternion.identity); //Spawn enemy
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    StartCoroutine(SpawnAnEnemy());

}

IEnumerator SpawnABoss()
{

    Vector2 spawnPos = GameObject.Find("Player").transform.position;
    spawnPos += Random.insideUnitCircle.normalized * spawnRadius; //Set allowable spawn point area for bosses around the player

    Instantiate(bossEnemy[Random.Range(0, enemies.Length)], spawnPos, Quaternion.identity); //Spawn boss
    
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(bossTime);
    //StartCoroutine(SpawnABoss());

}
```

}

I know it's not the prettiest code but it works, kinda. I really need this optimised cause my computer is a potato and its getting more and more difficult to playtest every time I want to add a new feature.

Comment: Try ecs? That’s why they are working on it

Comment: @BugFinder, for 10k units on screen this would be helpful. If it's 10k over a minute, but only 100 on screen at the same time, you could just use Object Pooling. (Imagine they die the whole time because player uses a minigun...)

Comment: @KYL3R you are exactly right. the enemies die en mass and i need to try and spawn and kill them very quickly

Answer (score 1):

0. Use Window->[Profiler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html) to see which steps/scripts actually take up most time.
1. [Object Pooling](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/introduction-to-object-pooling). Basically, instead of "Instantiate" & "Destroy" you keep filling your pool with Instantiate, but disable instead of destroy. Then, instead of instantiate, you just enable objects and update position, reset health etc. This improves memory handling, garbage collection etc. You can look for a pooling solution or just use an Array/List and manage it yourself.
2. [DOTS/ECS](https://unity.com/de/dots).  Unity can handle a TON of entities when you use the Data oriented / entitiy component system. That is a bit different way to program and handle your data.
3. Unity supports [Havoc Physics](https://unity.com/de/unity/physics) when using DOTS/ECS. That may help increase performance with your Rigidbodies.

Comment: thank you. ill be sure to try object pooling first cause im still kinda new to programming

Comment: I think object pooling would help a LOT in your case.